# Firefox keeps opening Facebook and home page on startup

Tags: windows-7, firefox, facebook

I just installed firefox 8 for the first time on a freshly formatted computer. I noticed that for some reason it opens up facebook and my home page everytime it starts up. I don't want it to load facebook up every single time I start firefox.

How can I stop this? I tried to close the tab and then restart firefox but it just keeps coming back.

Answer (score 3):

- Click the Firefox(Orange color) button on left top corner of the browser,click options->options
- Now choose show a blank page, or choose the options you want,and click ok.Thats it.
  [image]

Comment: Ya I checked there. What was happening was for some reason facebook was set to my homepage and some how msn must have been set as well(but now show in the home page area). So I just put msn back to my homepage and now I don't get dual tabs.

Comment: If you want to get dual tabs means,just add website links in Home Page text box which shown above,Example: "http ://www.google.com | http ://www.msn.com | http ://www.facebook.com." the separator "|" is important . So now every restart of your browser these websites will show you as a homepage .